# child div outside the parent

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I am currently designing a website . But in one of my parent div `box_t`,the child divs `box_t1` and `box_t2` goes outside the `box_t`.

**Html**:

```
<div id="main_container">
  <div class="box_t">
    <div class="box_t1">
      <h2>Start</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box_t2">
      <div class="boxt21">
        <h2>Name</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="boxt22">
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#main_container
{
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.box_t
{
  padding:20px 14px 20px 15px;
  color:#07337a;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box_t h2
{
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.box_t1
{
  width:340px;
  float:left;
}
.box_t2
{
  float:left;
}
.box_t2
{
  margin-left:255px;
}
.boxt21
{
  float:left;
}
.boxt22
{
  float:left;
}
```

[image: Dreamweaver design and code view]

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your child divs are not going outside the parent div, but what you see on dream waver is due to dream waver's style of displaying the html contents.

Check actual rendering of your code in browser

Comment: there is option in dream waver to select design mode on top left corner, you can see the rendering over there or use split view to see both the view at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You should use clearfix for parent block.
There a lot of ways to do it set `overflow:hidden` or set at bottom element with `clear: both` empty block inside parent.
My fav way is:

```
  // for modern browsers
  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
     clear: both;
  }

  /* IE6-7 */
  .clearfix {
     zoom: 1;
  }
```

Use it class on your parent div and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you use the `float` for your div. Do remember to `clear` the float.The whole problem is that `floated objects do not add to the height` of the object the reside in properly. And hence child div appear to be outside of parent div.All we need to do is clear the float, and this entire problem goes away. Put this empty div AFTER your last floated object:

`<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floats

```
<div id="main_container">
<div class="box_t">
            <div class="box_t1">
                <h2>Start</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box_t2">
                <div class="boxt21">
                    <h2>Name</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="boxt22">
                    Hi
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
    </div>
```

There is a better way to do this, create a class called `clearfix` and add it to the br... well really you should even include a br... but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using borders (style="border:1px solid red") on all the div while developing a layout, it helps to know where exactly the divs are positioned.

This helps developers who dont use Dreamweaver or other editing tools.